# Is it possible to change $rootScope variables through a Service Worker?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have an application in AngularJS that receives notifications via Firebase Messaging. Inside the application I have a notification counter.

For the internal notifications the Angular application save the count in a $rootScope variable: $rootScope.unseenCount

My problem is to change this count when I receive a external notification on desktop. Because this kind of notification is controled by the firebase-messaging-sw and didn't pass througt my AngularJS application.

What are the alternatives for solving this problem? I need examples if it's possible.

I try to register the service worker in the angular application but without success.

Already try to make a POST message from the service worker to angular application. The application can't listen to the post.